# Get more than 1 result set for recursive CTE?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a simple table which has leafs and sub leafs info. ( like a forum questions)

A *main* message is defined where `childId` and `ParentID` are the same

[image]

So here we see 2 main questions and their answers.

I've also managed to calc the depth of each element :

[image]

In  short this is the main query :

```
    WITH CTE AS
    (
       SELECT childID
             ,parentID,
             0 AS depth,name
       FROM   @myTable
       WHERE   childID = parentID AND childID=1 -- problem line
       
       UNION ALL
       
       SELECT TBL.childID
             ,TBL.parentID,
              CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name 
       FROM   @myTable AS TBL
               INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
       WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
    )
    SELECT childID,parentID,REPLICATE('----', depth) + name
```

But the problem is Line #8 (commented).

I currently ask *"give me all the cluster for question id #1"*

So where is the problem ?

I want to have **multiple** result set  , for each question !

so here i need to have 2 result sets :

one for `childId=parentId=1`
and one for
one for `childId=parentId=6`

[**full working sql online**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/127197)

*(and I dont want to use cursor)*

Comment: For what reason do you want multiple record-sets (one record-set for every question) ?

Comment: Each question is binded to html repeater that's why , and i have other manipulation that i should do for each question

Comment: If you want multiple result sets, why don't you want to use a cursor? Do you think there is a way to represent multiple result sets while SQL Server behaves there is a single set? What performance problem do you think a cursor is going to add to the approach you're trying to take?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it׳s just that ive heard so many bad things about it:) but if you say it is fine , then who am i to disagree . Ps what did you mean "controlling cursor loop" ?

Comment: @Royi stop placing artificial limitations on yourself based on things you've heard. Based on your requirements a cursor (or while loop, which is a cursor) seems like the way you're going to need to do this, unless you can change your requirement to achieve the end result without something that requires it - why can't you use a simple DataReader? As for specifying cursor options, see [this post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To present multiple result sets to your client, you're going to have to use a cursor or a while loop to perform independent `SELECT` operations. You can't do that from a CTE, since a CTE can only be used by exactly one subsequent query.

Now, the source of the problem has nothing to do with cursors really, but the fact that you're using an HTML repeater. Why do you need to use an HTML repeater for this? A simple DataReader can loop through all of the results from the CTE's *single set*, and make conditional formatting decisions based on the loop and determining when the root ID changes. So I suggest you look into solving the presentation problem a different way, rather than trying to coerce SQL Server to accommodate your presentation implementation.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I see the image but I fail to understand how you can't generate that presentation with a single result set. You just need more logic in your client-side code to generate the necessary HTML, and it would probably also be more efficient than using `n` HTML repeaters.

Comment: "_more logic in your client-side code to generate the necessary HTML_" : no problem with that , it's just that i thought : "let the sql do the hard work and digest all the data ."

Comment: @Royi nope, going back to your "cursors are bad" perception, SQL is good at sets. Your client code has to loop anyway - so let *it* keep track of when certain column values change while it is looping. No sense in making SQL Server loop *and* make your client code loop too.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and correcting me for my mistakes and perception mistakes. I will do it with single result (section-sorted) set. so no cursor is needed here (right?) ( if im doing all the filtering while rendering)....

Comment: ( a bit off-topic) but why I don't get the `order by` that i set ? I mean  - if i want to control the order of appearence of 2 brothers ( `c` and `d` ) in my question , I added `order by` and it doesn't work. what am i missing ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/m0jWE.png

Comment: please ignore my last comment. I guess I have trouble with the outmost `order by`...I will try (hopefully) to solve it.

Comment: @Royi it looks like you need the CTE to expose the location, then you can include that in the outer `ORDER BY`. In the graphic you said "I told it to search by location" but I don't see how that is possible. The final result does not have to obey the order inside the CTE (and it looks syntactically incorrect anyway).

Comment: Exposed it , any way it seems like a new question to ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036417/controlling-the-sibling-order-under-recursive-cte cuz I'm getting hard to understand why doesnt it work.

Answer (score 9):

You can build your queries dynamically.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) =
(SELECT '
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT childID
         ,parentID,
         0 AS depth,name
   FROM   myTable
   WHERE   childID = parentID AND childID = '+CAST(childID AS NVARCHAR(10))+'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT TBL.childID
         ,TBL.parentID,
          CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name 
   FROM   myTable AS TBL
           INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
   WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT childID,parentID,REPLICATE(''----'', depth) + name
FROM   CTE   
ORDER BY
      childID;'

FROM  myTable
WHERE childID = parentID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Update:

As suggested by Bogdan Sahlean we can minimize compilations by making the actual query parameterized.

```
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT childID
         ,parentID,
         0 AS depth,name
   FROM   myTable
   WHERE   childID = parentID AND childID = @childID

   UNION ALL

   SELECT TBL.childID
         ,TBL.parentID,
          CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name 
   FROM   myTable AS TBL
           INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
   WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT childID,parentID,REPLICATE(''----'', depth) + name
FROM   CTE   
ORDER BY
      childID;'

DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX) =
(SELECT 'exec sp_executesql @SQL, N''@childID int'', '+CAST(childID AS NVARCHAR(10))+';'
FROM  myTable
WHERE childID = parentID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL2, N'@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)', @SQL1;
```

Comment: You could use a parameter (`WHERE ... childID = @param`) to minimize plan compilation and to promote plan reuse.

Comment: @Bogdan that would be much more complex and I think would require nested dynamic SQL. Note that the query actually generates many CTE queries, one for each distinct `ChildID` - can you show how a simple parameter could be used here?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Yes. That would mean the the query itself is static and I have to build the calls to sp_executesql dynamically and call that with sp_executesql.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Added a version that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "returning two result sets".  Could you just have *one* result set, with the root question being assigned into another column?  The following tweak on your query does this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT ChildId as WhichQuestion, childID, parentID, 0 AS depth, name
      FROM   @myTable
      WHERE   childID = parentID
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cte.WhichQuestion, TBL.childID, TBL.parentID, CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name 
      FROM   @myTable AS TBL
            INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
      WHERE   TBL.childID <> TBL.parentID
    )
SELECT WhichQuestion, childID, parentID, REPLICATE('----', depth) + name     
FROM   CTE   
ORDER BY WhichQuestion, childID;
```

Comment: He has an HTML repeater, so currently the output is needed in independent `SELECT` statements (which can't come from a CTE, obviously). Thankfully I've convinced him that he should change his client-side code to deal with a single result set instead of changing his query to satisfy the HTML repeater.

Answer (score -2):

You can save in anchor part childId of root question and then access all the branch by needed Id:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT childID as RootId
        , childID
        , parentID
        , 0 AS depth,name
    FROM @myTable
    WHERE childID = parentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.RootId
        , TBL.childID
        , TBL.parentID
        , CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name 
    FROM @myTable AS TBL
    INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
    WHERE TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
```

Comment: How will this return multiple independent result sets? Can you finish the query?

Comment: This query doesn't return multiple result sets "as is". But you can access it by needed ids when you need.
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RootId = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RootId = 6

Comment: Can you show how please? Otherwise I'm not sure how this is different really than the CTE the OP already has, nor am I clear how it meets the actual requirement that spurred his question in the first place.