# Controlling the sibling order under recursive CTE?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

I have a CTE query which looks for main leafs and sub leafs. but I'm having trouble controling the leaf selection order **between 2 siblings** :

Each row in the table is declared as :

`(childID INT ,parentID INT ,NAME NVARCHAR(30),location int)`

Where `location` is a priority to sort IFF they are siblings.

And so  I have this tree structure :  those pairs has a location priority :

[image]

For example :

```
`a` ( location=1) should be before `f` (location=2)
`b` ( location=1) should be before `e` (location=2)
`d` ( location=1) should be **before** `c` (location=2)
```

The problem is that it seems that I must **first** `order by` `childID` in order to see the right  structure ( *sibling unsorted*).

But  - what how does my `order by` should look like so I will be able to see the right structure   (**&& sibling sorted**) ?

*(in my example : `d` should come before `c`)*

[**Here is the working query which yields all the tree leafs ( unsorted siblings)**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/127231)

p.s. `childID` is **not** indicating anything about the sorting. it's just a placeholder. as I said , the location between 2 brothers is by the `location` column.( here  , childId is sorted because thats the order of which i inserted the rows...

Comment: @downvoter , Downvoting without a comment or explanation to such detailed question - is not the spirit of this site. -Reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate path of the tree node in your CTE and use it for sorting

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT childID, parentID, 0 AS depth, NAME , location,
         cast(location as varbinary(max)) path
   FROM   @myTable
   WHERE   childID = parentID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TBL.childID, TBL.parentID,
           CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name ,TBL.location,
           cte.path + cast(TBL.location as binary(4))
    FROM   @myTable AS TBL
            INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
    WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT depth, childID, parentID, location, REPLICATE('----', depth) + name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY path
```

Comment: Those tricks etc makes me feel really really stupid. :-) ( but I'm happy to learn this technique).-- p.s. it is working.

Comment: Typically the `location` is left-padded with zeroes to ensure that it is a fixed width for each level, e.g. `Right( '00000' + Cast( Tbl.Location as VarChar(6) ), 6 )`. That avoids any oddities with sorting numbers alphabetically.

Comment: @HABO, right, thanks, corrected (but I used a bit different, which retain same logic, but a bit shorter visually)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, HABO did important notice, please see updated answer, so that you don't get for example `1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 4, 5 ..` when number of siblings is large enough.

Comment: @i-one I dont understand the problem with yourt first solution this is working fine for me http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/127299 **please explain**

Comment: @HABO can you please see my last comment ? I dont see what's the problem with the original solution ...(http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/127299)

Comment: @HABO can you please post your solution to with the padding ? so that other people can see it also :-) ?

Answer (score 3):

The following is i-one's answer modified, at Royi Namir's request, to use left-padded numeric strings for the path:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT childID, parentID, 0 AS depth, NAME , location,
         Cast( Right( '00000' + Cast( Location as VarChar(6) ), 6 ) as  VarChar(1024) ) as Path
   FROM   @myTable
   WHERE   childID = parentID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TBL.childID, TBL.parentID,
           CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name ,TBL.location,
           Cast( cte.Path + '.' + Right( '00000' + Cast( Tbl.Location as VarChar(6) ), 6 ) as VarChar(1024) )
    FROM   @myTable AS TBL
            INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
    WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT depth, childID, parentID, location, REPLICATE('----', depth) + name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY path
```

**NB: Untested and written on vacation.**

The separators (`.`) are not required, but make the resulting values easier to read and may simplify some operations, e.g. finding common sub-paths.

Comment: Thanks! have a nice vacation!

Comment: Can u please have a look at my related question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064928/cte-query-wont-yield-the-right-structure-when-printing

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Apparently not.  "Voluntarily removed by its author."

Comment: , sorry I thought it is more appropriate to DB site so i moved it  : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47585/cte-query-doesnt-print-the-right-structure - thanks for your effort.